# How are Go closures layed out in memory?

Tags: go, closures

*For an explanation of closures in general, see [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)*

How exactly are Go closures laid out in memory?

Take, for example, the following function:

```
type M int

func (m *M) Adder(amount int) func() {
    return func() {
        *m = *m + amount
    }
}
```

When our code calls `a := m.Adder()`, how much memory is allocated on the heap and what does it look like? How much memory does the returned `func()` value take up (wherever in memory it ends up being)?

Comment: Looks like the `funcval` struct in runtime/runtime2.go would be of use.

Comment: The other question is about _how_ the closures work in practice, but what you’re asking is for implementation details from an undefined version of a particular Go compiler. While it may be interesting, I don’t know if SO is the place to ask.

Comment: The golang FAQ might help: https://golang.org/doc/faq#stack_or_heap which is similar for all if is it functions/closures etc

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language
>   Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Function literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_literals)
>
> A function literal represents an anonymous function.
>
> `FunctionLit = "func" Signature FunctionBody .`
>
> `func(a, b int, z float64) bool { return a*b < int(z) }`
>
> A function literal can be assigned to a variable or invoked directly.
>
> ```
> f := func(x, y int) int { return x + y }
> func(ch chan int) { ch <- ACK }(replyChan)
> ```
>
> Function literals are closures: they may refer to variables defined in
>   a surrounding function. Those variables are then shared between the
>   surrounding function and the function literal, and they survive as
>   long as they are accessible.

---

> Closures may refer to variables defined in
>   a surrounding function. Those variables are then shared between the
>   surrounding function and the function literal, and they survive as
>   long as they are accessible.

Variables that survive a function call are put on the heap. In Go, closures are really that simple.

---

For example,

```
func closure() func() *byte {
    var b [4 * 1024]byte
    return func() *byte {
        return &b[0]
    }
}
```

A `closure()` call is two heap allocations, one for 16 (= 8 + 8 on amd64) bytes

```
struct { F uintptr; b *[4096]byte }
```

and one for 4096 bytes

```
[4096]byte
```

for a total of 4112 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

This blog post answers the question for the current version of the Go compiler:

https://philpearl.github.io/post/functionpointers/

> In Go as it is presently…
>
> - Function variables are pointers
> - They point to small structs
> - Those structs contain either
>
>   - just the pointer to the function code for simple functions
>   - or to pointers to autogenerated wrapper functions and receivers &/or function parameters in the case of method calls and closures.